# Indentation change after if-else expression not taken into account?

Tags: f#

Given this this operator for evaluation of side effects in pipelines

```
let inline (|>!) a f = f a ; a
```

and this code snippet

```
if 1 = 1 then  
    "same"
else 
    "different"  
|>! printfn "The numbers are %s." 
|>  printfn "Yes, they are %s."
```

This never prints `The numbers are same` but it does print `Yes, they are same`.

**Why is the side effect operator `|>!` ignored here, but the `|>` taken into account, despite having the same indent?**

**Would I have to define the side effect operator differently?**

written like this it works as expected.

```
if 1 = 1 then   "same"
else "different"  
|>! printfn "The numbers are %s." 
|>  printfn "Yes, they are %s."
```

Is it only unintuitive for me that the code actually behaves as if written

```
if 1 = 1 then  
    "same"
else 
    "different"  
    |>! printfn "The numbers are %s." // with indent here
|>  printfn "Yes, they are %s."
```

---

**Edit:**

see also https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/806 for an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a bug, and it doesn't happen specifically for operators longer than two characters. This is a funny consequence of F#'s permissive offset rules.

When aligning lines of the same nestedness level, they have to be at the same indentation, like this:

```
let foo =
     bar
     baz
     qux
```

But this is not allowed:

```
let foo =
     bar
      baz  // Indented too much to the left
     qux
```

And neither is this:

```
let foo =
     bar
    baz  // Indented too little
     qux
```

When dealing with constructs that create nested blocks, such as `if`/`then`, this rule is used to determine when the block is over: it's when the indentation alignment is broken.

```
let x =
     if 1 = 1 then
       bar
       baz
     qux
```

But there is an exception to this rule: **if the line starts with an operator, then it is allowed to be shifted to the left by at most the operator size plus 1 characters, and it will still be considered to be at "current" indentation**.

For example, this works:

```
let x =
       1
     + 2
     + 3
```

But when you have operators of different sizes, it gets tricky. This works:

```
let x =
       1
     + 2
     + 3
    <> 6
```

But this doesn't:

```
let x =
        1
     +  2
     +  3
     <> 6
```

this doesn't work because `2` and `3` are shifted to the left by **more** than the operator size plus one character.

---

So this is what happens in your case:

- The first `printfn` is considered to be part of the `else` block, because it happens to align exactly with `"different"`, but shifted to the left by operator size plus one.
- The second `printfn`, however, is shifted to the left by **more** than operator size plus one, so it's no longer part of the `else`.
- But it still happens to be correct syntax, because now it can be part of the surrounding block, with the whole result of `if`/`then`/`else` piped into it.
- Normally you'd get a syntax error, like in my example with `1+2+3 <> 6` above, but in this case the syntax happens to align just right (or, perhaps, *just wrong*).

You can verify this by removing the extra space in front of the second `printfn`:

```
if 1 = 1 then  
    "same"
else 
    "different"  
|>! printfn "The numbers are %s." 
 |> printfn "Yes, they are %s."
```

Now the second `printfn` will be part of the `else`, and you'll get an error: `types string and unit don't match`. This is because `then` returns a `string`, but `else` now returns a `unit`. This can be fixed by amending the `then` part:

```
if 1 = 1 then  
    ()
else 
    "different"  
|>! printfn "The numbers are %s." 
 |> printfn "Yes, they are %s."
```

Now this compiles and doesn't print anything. And if you replace `1 = 1` with `1 = 2`, it will correctly print "different" twice.

Finally, if you want the whole `if`/`then`/`else` block to be piped through both `printfn` calls, you have to break the alignment of `"different"` with the first `printfn` somehow. One way to do it you have offered yourself: putting `"different"` on the same line with `else`. Another way would be to indent `"different"` a bit further, so it no longer aligns with the first `printfn`:

```
if 1 = 1 then  
    "same"
else 
      "different"  
|>! printfn "The numbers are %s." 
|>  printfn "Yes, they are %s."
```

Comment: Interesting. That may be the defined behaviour but it seems unintuitive to me. I would be happy to have my operators line up on the left side (exactly as in idiomatic multi-line F# piping). The ability to "undent" for operators doesn't seem useful. I've never done it.

Comment: I think there is already a suggestion to add a warning for this: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/806