# Identical syntax is invalid when using a user-defined operator

Tags: f#

This code compiles and prints 5.

```
Some 5
|> function
| Some b -> 
    b
| None ->
    0
|> printfn "%d"
```

Now if define a new operator that does exactly what `|>` does, and replace the last `|>` with that new operator, the compiler produces an error I don't understand:

```
let inline (|>!) (a: 'T) (f: 'T -> 'U) = f a  
 
Some 5
|> function
| Some b -> 
    b
| None ->
    0
|>! printfn "%d" // FS0001: The type 'int' does not match the type 'unit'
```

Note that rearranging the code slightly fixes this again:

```
Some 5
|> function
| Some b -> b
| None -> 0
|>! printfn "%d"
```

I suspect a bug in the compiler, any other ideas?

Comment: Very serendipitously, I wrote an answer about this just a few weeks ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784154/indentation-change-after-if-else-expression-not-taken-into-account/64788185#64788185

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Wow! Much obliged.